# Outlook Add-in + WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, outlook-addin

Does anyone knows how to use WPF in Outlook Add-ins, I have read some blog posts and I realized that it's possible to add WPF controls in Outlook Add-in projects. I just want to host a complete WPF application in a Outlook Add-in. simple when outlook ribbon button clicks, it should open a WPF application, not a WPF controller hosted in a windows form, Can this be done?

Edited answer:

To use WPF in outlook Add-in projects, first add a WCF Usercontroller to the project and change the "UserController" to "Window" in both .XAML file and .CS file. Then you are done, You can do what ever you want with WCF. 
Change this >>

```
<UserControl x:Class="AccessCachedContactsTest.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

to this >>

```
<Window x:Class="AccessCachedContactsTest.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

And also change the root class of .xaml.cs file to "Window".

Comment: So you just want to start an application from with Outlook? should the application have any relation to Outlook?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use WPF in outlook Add-in projects, first add a WPF UserControl to the project and change the "UserControl" to "Window" in both .XAML file and .CS file. Then you are done, You can do what ever you want with WPF. Change this >>

```
<UserControl x:Class="AccessCachedContactsTest.UserControl2"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
     <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

to this >>

```
<Window x:Class="AccessCachedContactsTest.UserControl2"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

And also change the root class of .xaml.cs file to "Window".

Comment: Are there any caveats with this approach?  It seems to work fine, but I notice how little "points" this Q&A have received....

Comment: It works fine for me, I have a working solution with out any problem. There's no other direct way you can do that, even I did a lot of research and finally ended up using this method :)

Comment: Is there a minimal outlook version to be able to use this approach? (outlook 2010++ or outlook 2013++)